# Check if a TextView's text is completely displayed with Android Espresso

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-espresso

In Espresso it's possible to check if the view is displayed:

```
onView(withText("To create a test configuration in Android Studio, complete the following steps")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

But what I need to check is if the text of my `TextView` is completely displayed (not the `TextView` itself). Here is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="#fca"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If the text of the `TextView` is "To create a test configuration in Android Studio, complete the following steps," it's not completely displayed:

[image]

If the text is shorter, I see it all:

[image]

Putting the `TextView` in a `ScrollView` is not an option. 
[Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html) is not an option, either.

Sure, I could change the text and make sure it's completely displayed using the Preview view of the XML layout editor in Android Studio. But what if I have 6 locales, 9 emulators and 5 screens to check. 6 * 9 * 5 = 270 screens! It's time-consuming to test this thing manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not directly answering your questions, here are suggestions:

- Use pseudo-localization to manually test only once

Pseudo-localization is a testing method available in Android that will replace your production-texts with test-texts that usually cause UI/translation problems.
Basically if your app is still readable with a pseudo-locale, you're good to go.

doc on how to use it: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/pseudolocales.html

- Starting the version 26.0 from the Support Library you can use auto sizing on your TextView to make sure your tests are always displayed

TextView is now capable of automatically shrinking the text font size so that the whole text fits within its boundaries.

doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that Autosizing TextViews wasn't an option, either. But I'm going to check out [Pseudolocales](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/pseudolocales.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [LayoutAsserions.noEllipsizedText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/assertion/LayoutAssertions.html) that checks for cut-off and ellipsized text combined with something like [Screengrab](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/screengrab/) that lets you change the locale of the device during the test execution.

I am not sure how to solve the device fragmentation without launching multiple emulators(devices), but I think you can generalize them by their pixel density and do device rotation if needed during the test run as well.

Comment: This one "LayoutAsserions.noEllipsizedText()" works only if the text is ellipsized not when the text is cut off. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The LayoutAsserions.noEllipsizedText() seems to work only when text is ellipsized (I've checked with restricting parent view to make the inner textview cutoff.

(also the matcher isCompletelyDisplayed() is also not working)

So decided to check the visible rect and the actual rect it needed to display it fully.

My CustomMatcher is like this

```
override fun matchesSafely(textView: TextView): Boolean {
    val measuredWidth = textView.measuredWidth
    val measuredHeight = textView.measuredHeight

    // measure is called to find out how big a view should be.
    textView.measure(0, 0)
    val actualWidth: Int = textView.measuredWidth
    val actualHeight: Int = textView.measuredHeight

    return measuredWidth >= actualWidth  && measuredHeight >= actualHeight
}
```

using a BoundMatcher<View, TextView>. I think this can be used for any views getting cut off i think.